# Why is only one letter of this font displaying?

Tags: fonts, typography

`GotIn.fd` is a decorative initial font created by Dieter Steffman. It can be found on CTAN [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/initials/). While drafting, I've been experimenting with numerous decorative initial fonts found at [this archive](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/otherfonts.html). A number of them work as expected. EG

```
% ...within the preamble...
\input{Typocaps.fd}

% ...later in the document...
{\Huge\usefont{U}{Typocaps}{xl}{n}Check out this cool font!}\\
```

produces this output:

[image: Typocaps.fd working as intended]

This is not the case with `GotIn.fd`. EG:

```
% ...within the preamble...
\input{GotIn.fd}

% ...later in the document...
{\Huge\usefont{U}{GotIn}{xl}{n}Check out this cool font!}\\
```

produces this output:

[image: GotIn.fd not working as intended]

I am not clear what is going on here. Numerous other fonts from the same archive work as intended. A number of them last updated well before `GotIn.fd`. Maybe a more experienced LaTeX user can speak to this.

P.S., I'm using overleaf.

Comment: Probably the font has only uppercase letters.

Comment: Confirmed that by examining the font in FontForge (https://fontforge.org/en-US/).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We generally prefer to work with "minimal working examples", so that we can copy/paste and immediately see what you're talking about.  In this case, I think that just means adding `\documentclass{article} ... \begin{document} ... \end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

@Thérèse was correct in their comment. The font requires the inputted characters be uppercase. Adjusting the code to be such:

```
% ...within the preamble...
\input{GotIn.fd}

% ...later in the document...
{\Huge\usefont{U}{GotIn}{xl}{n}CHECK OUT THIS COOL FONT!}\\
```

outputs the desired result. Thank you!

Comment: Suggestion: Always put `\tracinglostchars=2` in all your TeX files, especially when fiddling with fonts: otherwise the warning message about missing characters in fonts appears only in the log file. (A design flaw in TeX IMO: it should have been possible to make it a fatal error.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm certain this should be a default feature when using the `[draft]` option.